# Change values of a timedelta column based on the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

Let it be the following Python Panda Dataframe:

| code | visit_time | flag | other | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 0 | 1 days 03:00:12 | False | Y | 1 |
| 0 | NaT | False | X | 3 |
| 0 | 0 days 05:00:00 | True | X | 2 |
| 1 | NaT | False | Z | 3 |
| 1 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 1 | 1 days 03:00:12 | False | Y | 1 |
| 2 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 2 | 5 days 10:01:12 | True | Y | 0 |

To solve the problem, only the columns: `code, visit_time` and `flag` are needed.

Each row with a value of `visit_time`, has a previous row with value `NaT`. Knowing this, I want to do next modification in the dataframe:

- Sets the flag of the row with non-null value of `visit_time` to the same value as its previous row.

Example:

| code | visit_time | flag | other | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 0 | 1 days 03:00:12 | True | Y | 1 |
| 0 | NaT | False | X | 3 |
| 0 | 0 days 05:00:00 | False | X | 2 |
| 1 | NaT | False | Z | 3 |
| 1 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 1 | 1 days 03:00:12 | True | Y | 1 |
| 2 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 2 | 5 days 10:01:12 | True | Y | 0 |

I am grateful for the help offered in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.mask` to set the `'flag'` values to the `.shift`ed version of itself where `'visit_time'` values are `notnull`.

```py
out = df.assign(
    flag=df['flag'].mask(df['visit_time'].notnull(), df['flag'].shift())
)

print(out)
   code      visit_time   flag other  counter
0     0             NaT   True     X        3
1     0 1 days 03:00:12   True     Y        1
2     0             NaT  False     X        3
3     0 0 days 05:00:00  False     X        2
4     1             NaT  False     Z        3
5     1             NaT   True     X        3
6     1 1 days 03:00:12   True     Y        1
7     2             NaT   True     X        3
8     2 5 days 10:01:12   True     Y        0
```

- `.mask(condition, other)` replaces values where condition is True with the values of `other` in this case `other` is the value from the previous row.
- `.assign(…)` is a way to update a column while returning a new `DataFrame` this can be replaced with column assignment `df['flag'] = df['flag'].where(…)` to modify the `DataFrame` in place.

---

Creating a column from a string variable.

```py
df[name] = df[name].mask(df['visit_time'].notnull(), df[name].shift()))
```

Comment: I think it's a very good solution, but I suppose I store the ```flag``` column in a ```name``` variable. ```df = df.assign(name=df[name].mask(df['visit_time'].notnull(), df[name].shift()))``` This has the problem that it creates a new ```name``` column. How can I fix it?

Comment: just updated my answer to show how you can do this

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have a shifted dataframe as in:

```
df_previous = df.copy()
df_previous.index+=1
```

Looking like:

|  | code | visit_time | flag | other | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 days 03:00:12 | False | Y | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | NaT | False | X | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 days 05:00:00 | True | X | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | NaT | False | Z | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 days 03:00:12 | False | Y | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 9 | 2 | 5 days 10:01:12 | True | Y | 0 |

Now you can have it merge with original dataframe and assign values with simple  vector comparisons:

```
df = df.merge(df_previous[['visit_time', 'flag']], right_index=True, left_index=True, how='left', suffixes=["",'_previous'])
df.loc[df.visit_time.notna(), 'flag'] = df.loc[df.visit_time.notna(), 'flag_previous']
```

Now your dataframe looks like:

|  | code | visit_time | flag | other | counter | visit_time_previous | flag_previous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | NaT | True | X | 3 | nan | nan |
| 1 | 0 | 1 days 03:00:12 | True | Y | 1 | NaT | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | NaT | False | X | 3 | 1 days 03:00:12 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 days 05:00:00 | False | X | 2 | NaT | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | NaT | False | Z | 3 | 0 days 05:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | NaT | True | X | 3 | NaT | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 days 03:00:12 | True | Y | 1 | NaT | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | NaT | True | X | 3 | 1 days 03:00:12 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 5 days 10:01:12 | True | Y | 0 | NaT | 1 |

You can also remove previous columns if you like with:

```
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = '_previous')), axis = 1)
```

Which will leave you with:

|  | code | visit_time | flag | other | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 days 03:00:12 | True | Y | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | NaT | False | X | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 days 05:00:00 | False | X | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | NaT | False | Z | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 days 03:00:12 | True | Y | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | NaT | True | X | 3 |
| 8 | 2 | 5 days 10:01:12 | True | Y | 0 |

Answer (score -1):

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] < df.shape[0] - 1:  # stop comparing when getting to last row
        if df.at[row[0], 'visit_time'] == 'NaT' and df.at[row[0] + 1, 'visit_time'] != 'NaT':
            df.at[row[0] + 1, 'flag'] = df.at[row[0], 'flag']
```

Before:

```
   code       visit_time   flag other  counter
0     0              NaT   True     X        3
1     0  1 days 03:00:12  False     Y        1
2     0              NaT  False     X        3
3     0  0 days 05:00:00   True     X        2
4     1              NaT  False     Z        3
5     1              NaT   True     X        3
6     1  1 days 03:00:12  False     Y        1
7     2              NaT   True     X        3
8     2  5 days 10:01:12   True     Y        0
```

After:

```
   code       visit_time   flag other  counter
0     0              NaT   True     X        3
1     0  1 days 03:00:12   True     Y        1
2     0              NaT  False     X        3
3     0  0 days 05:00:00  False     X        2
4     1              NaT  False     Z        3
5     1              NaT   True     X        3
6     1  1 days 03:00:12   True     Y        1
7     2              NaT   True     X        3
8     2  5 days 10:01:12   True     Y        0
```

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear, so I've edited the problem to see if it's clearer. Only the previous row has to be taken into account, not the next row.

Comment: It is much more straightforward. Updated.

Comment: General rule of thumb is if you are using for loop with pandas, you can do it better